# What is the difference in returning "JsonResult/IActionResult" or "Task<SomeObject>" or just "SomeObject" in a Asp.net Core Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Consider the following method signatures for an ASP.NET Core web API controller method:

```
public JsonResult GetById(string id);
public async Task<SomeObject> GetById(string id);
public SomeObject GetById(string id)
```

In the default setup, all return a JSON representation of `SomeObject` to the client.  Does the framework treat them differently, and if so which should be used when?

For example, most documentation recommends the use of an implementation of `IActionResult` generated by helper functions such as `OK()`.  However, all these seem to do for you is set the StatusCode, and they have the downside of obfuscating what your method returns - in fact you could return different types in different situations, which I think is a terrible idea.  A knock-on effect is that tools like Swagger cannot predict what the method will return.

So I'd prefer to return `SomeObject`:

1. am I missing something important?, and
2. What are the benefits of returning `Task<SomeObject>` - is it always useful, or only if the method uses asynchronous calls?

**Edit:** Attempt to clarify - all signatures return a JSON representation of `SomeObject` to the client, but from a C# point of view they have different return types, so the MVC framework is doing some work to convert them.

Which is best practice and why?  Is there a good reason to return `JsonResult` rather than returning `SomeObject`?  Should returning `Task<SomeObject>` always be used, or is it only valuable (I'd assume) if the action has async code in it?

Comment: Asynchronous methods are prepended with  `async Task` so you could have the method
`public async Task<JsonResult> GetById(string id);`

What you are asking is what is the difference between JsonResult and SomeObject? One returns an object with properties. The other returns Json format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you searching is what is `formatters` in ASP.NET Core and how they work. From official documentation:

> An action isn’t required to return any particular type; MVC supports any object return value. If an action returns an IActionResult implementation and the controller inherits from Controller, developers have many helper methods corresponding to many of the choices. Results from actions that return objects that are not IActionResult types will be serialized using the appropriate IOutputFormatter implementation.

You also need to read about `Content Negotiation`:

> Content negotiation only takes place if an Accept header appears in the request. When a request contains an accept header, the framework will enumerate the media types in the accept header in preference order and will try to find a formatter that can produce a response in one of the formats specified by the accept header. In case no formatter is found that can satisfy the client’s request, the framework will try to find the first formatter that can produce a response (unless the developer has configured the option on MvcOptions to return 406 Not Acceptable instead).

and finally in scope of `JsonResult` using:

> Actions can return specific results that are always formatted in a particular manner. For example, returning a JsonResult will return JSON-formatted data, regardless of client preferences.

Read more in [Formatting Response Data](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/formatting.html?highlight=jsonresult) section.

Comment: Thanks Set, I actually have read and understand all of these.  I will clarify my question, but in essence it is this: All these signatures return a JSON representation of `SomeObject` to the client; clearly the MVC framework is working under the hood to achieve that, since on the face of it they return different results; what are the reasons I should choose one over the other, or does it not matter?

Comment: That depends on what you want to provide for clients as response. Are clients always need result only in JSON format, or you would like to support content negotiation and return data in different format accordingly to provided Accept header? As simple example, if you use JsonResult, client will not have a possibility to  retrieve result in XML format, or any other not JSON format.